# Boundary of pseudospectra

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, matrix-analysis, matrix-theory

Suppose:

- $B_i \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$, $0<w_i\in \mathbb{R}$ $(i = 0,1,2,\ldots,m)$
- ${\rm P}(x) ={\rm{B}_m} x ^m + \cdots + B_1 x  + B_0$ is a matrix polynomial,  and $x $ is a complex variable.
- ${\rm q}(x) =\rm{w}_m x^m + \cdots +w_1 x + w_0$
- $U= \left\{ {x  \in \mathbb{C}:\left\| P(x)^{-1} \right\| \ge (\varepsilon q(|x|))}^{-1} \right\}$, where $\left\| \cdot \right\|$ is any subordinate matrix norm and the boundary of $U$ denote by $\partial U$.
- $S = \left\{ x  \in \mathbb{C}:\left\| P(x )^{-1} \right\| = (\varepsilon q(|x|))^{-1} \right\}$

Can we say that $S \subseteq \partial U$?

Comment: If $P(x)$ and $q(x)$ are constant, and if $\epsilon$ be such that $\|P(x)^{-1}\|=(\epsilon q(|x|))^{-1}$ then the result is not correct, for, $S=U$ and $U=\mathbb C$ which its boundary is empty.

Comment: @MeisamSoleimaniMalekan $q(x)$ can't be constant because $\forall i\, w_i>0$.

Comment: @TZakrevskiy: I considered $q(x)$ to be "constant", not to be "zero". I assumed that $m=0$, $P(x)=B_0$, an invertible matrix, $q(x)=w_0>0$.